# For Loop on Dictionary Values Returning Incorrect Bool Value

Tags: loops, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I'm learning to code in python and am trying to write a Tic Tac Toe game. I've used a function to assess if the game has been drawn (there should only be one instance where this is True - where all the spaces in a 3x3 grid have been filled by Xs or Os), but it's returning an incorrect value for a particular arrangement of the grid.

When a player takes a go, the original dictionary values for the board (which are numbers 1-9) are replaced by Xs/Os (e.g. the below).

```
# board prior to starting game
board1 = {1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4', 5:'5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8:'8', 9:'9'}

# board after 3 turns
board4 = {1:'X', 2:'O', 3:'X', 4:'4', 5:'5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8:'8', 9:'9'}
```

Here's the function I'm using and the problem I'm encountering.

```
def game_drawn(board):
    for i in board.values():
        if i not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
            game_drawn = True
        else:
            game_drawn = False
    return game_drawn

board9 = {1:'X', 2:'O', 3:'X', 4:'O', 5:'O', 6: 'X', 7: '7', 8:'X', 9:'O'}

print(game_drawn(board9))

# calling the function on this particular arrangement returns True, when it should return False. I've not had this problem with any other arrangement of the grid.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e942F.png)

I tried asking the program to print each i value as the loop runs, followed by printing the result of the function; it seems that when the loop reaches the '7' it doesn't run the boolean operation but skips to the next value of i.

[results of testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apkvm.png)

Comment: Using a debugger to follow what `game_drawn` does would make crystal clear what the problem is.

Comment: It would help to understand you modified program's output to actually *see* the modified version of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of my `if` statement was incorrect: each iteration of `i` was overwriting the previous; so, as long as the value of the 9<sup>th</sup> position in the board != 9, the result of the function would be true.

I changed the function to write a Y or N value to a new list depending on whether the `i` value could be found in the list I'd compared to. Using a separate `if` statement, I could then assess whether the game had been won or drawn depending on whether an N value was present in the new list.

A bit of a circuitous way around the problem but it's working.

```
def game_drawn(board):
    drawn = []
    for i in board.values():
        if i not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
            drawn.append('Y')
        else:
            drawn.append('N')
    if 'N' in drawn:
        game_drawn = False
    else:
        game_drawn = True
    return game_drawn

board9 = {1:'X', 2:'O', 3:'X', 4:'O', 5:'O', 6: 'X', 7: '7', 8:'X', 9:'O'}

print('Board 9: ' + str(game_drawn(board9)))
```